# onclick event is not triggering

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function accept(s)
  {
    alert(s);
  }
 </script>

<input type="button" style="background-color:#e2e6f0;border:1px solid 
#DCDCDC;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:3px" 
value="accept" onclick="accept('28391135292739653997')">
```

Why the onclick event not triggering the accept function? I was expecting it to work. I thought it might be due to number of digits but it worked in my sample where I used 30 digits too. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work if you call it something other than `accept`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bt5Q3/

Comment: its working but Iam curious to know why the function accept() is ignored here ?

Answer (score 5):

It's because accept is the name of a property of the input element. So the onclick event is trying to call the accept property as a method, rather than the accept function you've defined. If you change it to:

```
onclick="window.accept('28391135292739653997')"
```

It will call the globally defined accept function.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the function with another name.

'accept' is a property of all HTML Inputs. So, when you are calling accept it is trying to access that property and can't invoke it as a function. This is a strange and new behaviour for me. But testing it, if you put

```
onclick="value = 'test';"
```

you will see that when you click it, the button's value will change into 'test'

Can someone explain this behaviour with the specification as background?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the name accept as a javascript function since the tag INPUT has an accept attribute itself. The javascript is trying to access the ACCESS property of the INPUT-tag.
Renaming your function to something else will make it work.

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/W9VND/28/

Good luck!